# How to "invert" data in a CSV-file with an array of values

Tags: python, excel, csv, excel-formula

My question is about CSV/Excel data.

I have a huge list in CSV/Excel where I want to "invert" the data from this:

```
ArticleNO;Reference<br>
TRX82056-4;428030,426532,422992<br>
TRX82058-4;428030,426532,422992
```

To this:

```
Reference,ArticleNO<br>
428030;TRX82056-4,TRX82058-4<br>
426532;TRX82056-4,TRX82058-4<br>
422992;TRX82056-4,TRX82058-4
```

Instead of having the "ArticleNO" as base and the "Reference" as an array of matches, to have the "Reference" as base and the "ArticleNO as an array of matches,

Is there anyone who has a good idea how to acheave this? Excel or Python maybe?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Had to do it a bit ugly-ish because I didn't feel like creating the file and writing it to a new one, but something like this should do it..

```
>>> old = """ArticleNO;Reference<br>
... TRX82056-4;428030,426532,422992<br>
... TRX82058-4;428030,426532,422992"""
>>> lines = old.split('\n')
>>> for line in lines:
...    parts = line.split(';')
...    print(parts[1] + ';' + parts[0])
...    
Reference<br>;ArticleNO
428030,426532,422992<br>;TRX82056-4
428030,426532,422992;TRX82058-4
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you seem to be tool agnostic, here's a way to do it in R:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df1 %>% mutate(Reference = strsplit(as.character(Reference),",")) %>% 
  unnest(Reference) %>% 
  group_by(Reference) %>% 
  summarize(ArticleNO = str_c(ArticleNO, collapse= ","))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Reference ArticleNO            
  <chr>     <chr>                
1 422992    TRX82056-4,TRX82058-4
2 426532    TRX82056-4,TRX82058-4
3 428030    TRX82056-4,TRX82058-4
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ArticleNO = c("TRX82056-4", "TRX82058-4"), Reference = c("428030,426532,422992", 
"428030,426532,422992")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

a naive approach can be to traverse the list of ArticleNO and nesting the traversal of each Reference inside it. This will take time prop to m*n I think.

so

```
for all ArticleNo
    for all Reference 
       append reference to a new array
       scan the complete list for the reference and add the ArticleNO in another column.
       and also change the prev. checked entries to something else to avoid rescanning
```

I haven't read any data structure course or I would have suggested a time saving algo also